# Reshape root disk from raid1 to raid5 on live system

Tags: centos7, grub2

I have server with CentOS 7 and grub2.

It is in hosting company so I can not reinstall it.

Server root `/` is installed on (mdadm) RAID1. Size is 4 TB, but is made somehow without EFI.

These is small `/boot`, also (mdadm) RAID1.

I can convert `/` to RAID5. It keeps (mdadm) UUID. However server does not boot after this change.

Unfortunately I have no way to "see" the console.

I can reboot the server in rescue mode, but I have no idea what to check.

I understand the information I am providing is not much, but if I am able to do that, I will use the same procedure on 6+ servers.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you regenerate the initramfs?

Comment: no I did not :) but I supposed there is raid5 driver there?

Comment: I did something else. I installed root / without raid, then shrink the partition and made fresh raid5 on the free space. Had to use Ubuntu, because in this company CentOS always come with XFS.